# Elasticsearch search_after, don't use _id for tie_breaker_field?

Tags: elasticsearch, pagination

In the Elasticsearch docs for the search_after API they say to use a field with unique values, but that they "do not recommend using the _id field". Can anyone explain the reasoning behind this?

**Edit**: Meant to include the link, [here it is](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/search-request-search-after.html)

Answer (score 3):

You need to read a bit further in [that paragraph](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-search-after):

> The _id field has a unique value per document but **it is not recommended to use it as a tiebreaker directly.**
> [...]
> **doc value are disabled on this field** so sorting on it requires to load a lot of data in memory.  Instead it is advised to duplicate (client side or with a set ingest processor) the content of the _id field in **another field that has doc value enabled** and to use this new field as the tiebreaker for the sort.

So the reason is simply that using `_id` as a tiebreaker will induce a lot of data to potentially be loaded into memory, which is never a good thing.